# How to create an Email Id using c#..?

Tags: c#

Hi I want to create a program that helps me to create an email id.I mean it fills the other details and I will only enter the captcha.. Is there any way to do it using c#..?

Comment: what email ID? On which server? Why do you want to do that? Do you want to send spam?

Comment: we hate SPAMMER! Do not support them!

Comment: No I just want to fill the form using c#. Lets say I want to create an email ID in gmail. I just want to fill forms using c#. I will store all the details in variable.Then I want to fill that and submit to the gmail using c#. Just to learn handling webpage using c#..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WebBrowser` control. Parse needed controls from html text, and then programitically input text

Comment: thanks for not supporting spam :) this method will be very hard to maintain - which is good in this case.

Comment: Yeh.. But I want to control a win 7 gadget using c#. How to call a javascript function using c#...if I use WebBrowser..?

Comment: here is nice article http://notions.okuda.ca/2009/06/11/calling-javascript-in-a-webbrowser-control-from-c/

Comment: Hi thanks Stecya.. That article solved my problem. I am trying to it with mshtml.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write HTML parser anyway or use existing one (I suppose there are a lot of open source projects). You can use WebBrowser as Stecya said, but I will recomend to use `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` bacause of such approach would be faster.